JPA criteriaBuilder / Hibernate boolean query clause issue
I'm currently working with JPA criteriaBuilder and Predicate isTrue is not working as expected.
Entity ->
    @Deprecated
    private String boolAsString;

    @Column(name = "boolAsString", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Convert(converter = BooleanStringONWithoutNullConverter.class)
    private boolean booleanValue;

@Converter
public class BooleanStringONWithoutNullConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String>
{

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean attribute)
    {
        return BooleanUtils.toString(attribute, "O", "N", "N");
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData)
    {
        return "O".equals(dbData);
    }
}

The idea was to use a boolean instead of the String representation (which seems to work). Things become more complicated with JPA criteria and this simple query :
        Root<Entity> root = criteriaQuery.from(Entity.class);
        Predicate equal = criteriaBuilder.isTrue(root.get(Entity_.booleanValue));

Then I have 2 differents results whether the query is run with an integration test (HSQLDB) or with the Java/Spring Boot application (postgre) :

IT with HSQLDB ->

   ...     where
            entity0_.boolAsString='O'


Same query with SpringBoot App and Postgre ->

   ...     where
            entity0_.boolAsString='N'

Lib versions :

org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.5:compile

I don't understand why the same query ends with a different output, I'd appreciate any help :)
Ran the same JPA query with 2 different databases, result is different

Ok the difference comes from a small difference of JPA configuration between both.
The cause is the presence of the property "hibernate.query.substitutions", "true=1 false=0" and this seems to be in conflict with the converter.
